# Simple flatbed scanner - but it must work in Windows 7 Prof x64 ?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, scanner

Any recommendations on a pretty basic flatbed scanner for light-duty text and graphics scanning? I don't need any fancy features like sheet feeder or anything like that - I just need to scan an occasional text document or picture.

A scan-to-PDF function would be nice.

An **absolute MUST** is compatibility with Windows 7 Professional in **64-bit edition** - no VM or Virtual XP mess - the scanner **MUST** have working Windows 7-x64 drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this link to see what other scanners are Windows 7 64 bit compatible](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Browse.aspx?type=Hardware&category=Printers%20%26%20Scanners&subcategory=Scanners&os=64-bit)

Here's an example: [Canon Canoscan LiDe 100](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Hardware&p=Canon%20CanoScan%20LiDE100%20USB%20Scanner&v=Canon&uid=2923B002&pf=1&pi=0&c=Printers%20%26%20Scanners&sc=Scanners&os=64-bit)

Comment: Thanks, I had my eye on that one, but unfortunately, my local Canon distributor couldn't even confirm that it works with Win7-x64 :-(

Answer (score 3):

I have a **Canon CanoScan LiDE 60** that works fine with Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bits.

Here is the [**Microsoft Compatibility**](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Hardware&p=Canon%20CanoScan%20LiDE%2060%20USB%20Scanner&v=Canon&uid=0337B001&pf=0&pi=0&s=lide%2060&os=64-bit) page about it.

Answer (score 1):

I've got an Epson Perfection V100 Photo (not sure if this is still available new) and while I'm typing this I'm scanning a few documents with it on Windows 7 Ultimate x64.